# Querying Transaction_Table to get Count

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to SQL and trying to get answers to the following questions. I have built the following answers that I know are incorrect. Can you please help me fix my queries.

There is a database Table Transaction_Table 
(with all the users’ transaction history, 
each row is a transaction) with four fields: 
user_id; timestamp; transaction_id; transaction_amount_in_usd

Rank customers with transactions in Jul’19 according to transaction amount

```
SELECT user_id, sum(transaction) from Transaction_Table
Order by sum(transaction) desc
Where date(timestamp) = 07-2019;
```

For each user_id, keep only one record with the highest transaction amount

```
Select user_id, transaction amount
from transaction_table
Order by transaction desc
Group by user_id
```

Report number of new customers in Jul’19

```
Select count(user_id), 
FROM TRANSACTION_TABLE
(Select * from transaction_table
Where date(timetamp) >= “07-2019”)
ORDER BY COUNT(USER_ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Rank customers with transactions in Jul’19 according to the transaction amount
Assuming your date is of date datatype

```
Select user_id, sum(transaction) 
From Transaction_Table
Where timestamp = '07-2019'
Order by sum(transaction) desc;
```

For each user_id, keep only one record with the highest transaction amount

No need to do Order by here as you want to just return one value i.e. the highest transaction amount

```
Select user_id, max(transaction_amount)
from transaction_table
Group by user_id
```

Report number of new customers in Jul’19 (Assuming there is no separate column to know if the user is new and considering all users >= 07-2019 as new users in the table)

```
Select count(user_id)
From transaction_table
Where timestamp >= '07-2019'
```

Comment: Hi Harshal, Thank you for your response. For the last one, its all new customers. Which means they should not have a transaction before July 19'. Users in July 2019 and beyond might have transactions prior to July 2019 also, so this solution doesn't work